# Distribution for ratio of dependent quadratic forms.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, quadratic-forms

Random vector $\mathbf{x}_{0}$ $\sim$ $\mathcal{N}\left(\boldsymbol{\mu}, \mathbf{\Sigma} \right)$ is a sum of two orthogonal random vectors:

$\mathbf{x}_{0}$ = $\mathbf{x}_{1}$ + $\mathbf{x}_{1}^{\perp}$, where:  $\mathbf{x}_{1}^{\text{T}} \mathbf{x}_{1}^{\perp}$ = $0$.

Can the quadratic form $\mathbf{x}_{0}^{\text{T}} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}_{0}$ be expressed in such a way that the quotient:

$s$ $=$ $\cfrac{\mathbf{x}_{0}^{\text{T}} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}_{0}}{\mathbf{x}_{1}^{\text{T}} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}_{1}}$

has a known (documented) distribution? I think a unitary matrix transformation per the helpful comment below, in addition to Cochran's Theorem, may be of utility here.

Comment: Is there a way you can make your question a little more precise. Employing a literal interpretation, this is not even true in the simplest of cases. Take $\boldsymbol{\mu} = 0$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma} = \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{I}$ and choose $\mathbf{x}_1 = (x_{0,1}, 0, \ldots, 0)$. Then $s$ cannot be $F$ distributed since $s \geq 1$ with probability 1.

Comment: (As a side note, since $\mathbf x_1^T \mathbf x_1^{\perp} = \mathbf x_1^T \mathbf Q^T \mathbf Q x_1^{\perp}$ for any orthogonal $\mathbf Q$ and by standard properties of the multivariate normal, without loss of generality we can assume $\mathbf A$ to be diagonal.)

Comment: I see your point. I will edit my question; I really just want to obtain a known distribution for the quotient.